# No keyword with name 'Run' found

Tags: java, robotframework

I can't run any command. I download robot framework jar file and start testing by:

`java -jar /home/robotFramework/robotframework-2.7.7.jar tests.tsv`

My test file:

```
Library    OperatingSystem

*Test Case*
Insert    [Tags]    test1
    [Timeout]    4 minutes
    Run     ls -l
```

What is wrong?

```
==============================================================================
Tests
==============================================================================
Insert                                                                | FAIL |
No keyword with name 'Run' found.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests                                                                 | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add `*Setting*` header to tsv file. This how it should start:

```
*Setting*
Library OperatingSystem
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something is not right with the indentation of your test file.