# Robotframework, AutoIt: Error message "No keyword with name 'Run' found"

Tags: python, robotframework, autoit

I am trying to execute my `autoit` script file

```
*** Settings ***
Library              AutoItLibrary


*** Keywords ***

Upload Front ID Image
    click element      ${FRONTIDUPLOADBTN}
    sleep               3s
    Run                 uploadAutoit.exe        ${AUTOIT_FILE_PATH}
```

all Test runs until step of AutoIt

[image: error displays]

Comment: You need to load another library? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293608/no-keyword-with-name-run-found

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No keyword with name 'Run' found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293608/no-keyword-with-name-run-found)

Comment: AutoItLibrary.Run  not from OS library

Comment: @OneCricketeer  99.9999% those are not related ...  AutoIt on rf uses COM on windows to talk to autoit dll itself.. If the dll doesn't get initialized properly, error is seen as "missing keywords".

Comment: @TheHungryCub ^ as said above, im pretty sure that answer is unrelated.

Comment: Did you install robotframework-autoitlibrary as Administrator ? See https://github.com/nokia/robotframework-autoitlibrary/?tab=readme-ov-file#installation

Comment: Please include errors or output as text, so that it (hint!!) can be easily searched online! As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].